# What are some good Haskell Primers/Tutorials for beginners?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

What are some good links for diving into Haskell and functional programming in general?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) is pretty good for a start.

Answer (score 17):

*[Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)* feels a bit like a Haskell version of *Why's (Poignant) Guide to Ruby*.  Lisperati has a neat [Haskell tutorial](http://lisperati.com/haskell/) based on making people happy at a picnic using simulated annealing; it only uses the word "monad" three times!

Comment: +1 for the Lisperati reference!

Answer (score 7):

There's also [Yet Another Haskell Tutorial](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~hal/htut/) and [A Gentle Introduction to Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to look at *Real World Haskell* then be sure to sign up for the [Real World Haskell Book Club](http://groups.google.com/group/real-world-haskell-book-club) which is a great discussion group and which will also be having regular virtual meeting to go chapter-by-chapter through the book.

Answer (score 1):

An oldie but a goodie: "[Haskell: The Craft of Functional Programming](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/craft2e/)"